# extended Hamming code

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Hello I am trying to do an exercise, but I got stuck on it since till now I was using Hamming $\require{cancel}\cancel{(7, 4)}$  $[8,4]$? and everything was going fine and I understand it. So I have the word $1??10010$, which was received over a binary erasure channel, which garbled the second and third bit, I have to find the second and the third bit, could you please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: try asking this in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ for more answers

Comment: With the "standard" generator matrix (see my answer) there is no word with last four bits $0010$ (both halves of all words have an even weight).
Therefore you should give us the check matrix or the generator matrix you are using. You should not assume that everybody uses the same ordering of columns that your textbook does. I am not assuming it either (hence the scare quotes), but I cannot help you unless you tell what the generator matrix is.

Answer (score 1):

If an errors-only decoding algorithm is available for a *binary* code,
then there is an easy way to decode erasures. For
this specific code, there *is* a decoding algorithm that can correct
single errors and detect two errors. So, the erasures-only decoding algorithm works as follows.

- **Step I:** Replace all the erasures by $0$ to create a purely binary "received"
  word $\mathbf r_0$ and apply the errors-only decoding algorithm  to find the
  most likely transmitted codeword $\mathbf c_0$. Note that it is possible that
  the decoding algorithm will *fail to decode* and report that there
  are two errors in $\mathbf r_0$ and it has no idea what the most likely 
  transmitted codeword is.
- **Step II:** Replace all the erasures by $1$ to create a purely binary "received"
  word $\mathbf r_1$ and apply the errors-only decoding algorithm  to find the
  most likely transmitted codeword $\mathbf c_1$. Note that it is possible that
  the decoding algorithm will *fail to decode* and report that there
  are two errors in $\mathbf r_1$ and it has no idea what the most likely 
  transmitted codeword is.

Now the replacements of the erasures are guaranteed to produce one
of two possible results:

(i) exactly one of $\mathbf r_0$ and $\mathbf r_1$ is indeed
a valid codeword, and so that particular decoding will produce 
a most likely transmitted codeword while the other decoding will
result in a decoding failure,

and

(ii) both $\mathbf r_0$ and $\mathbf r_1$ are at distance $1$ from a codeword $\mathbf c$ and
so both decodings will result in $\mathbf c$ being returned as the most likely transmitted codeword.

Consequently, Step III of the erasures-only decoding algorithm is

- **Step III:** If exactly one Step I or Step II results
  in a valid codeword,
  return that codeword as the most likely transmitted codeword. If both Steps I and II return the same valid codeword, return that codeword
  as the most likely transmitted codeword.

---

**Note added in response to Jyrki Lahtonen's comments:**
The answer above was written in response to the specific question about the binary $[8,4]$ extended Hamming code, but, as noted in Jyrki's comments, with just a
minor modification, the algorithm also works for arbitrary binary
codes on an *errors-and-erasures* channel instead of the
erasures only channel.

A binary code with minimum distance $d$ can correct up to
$t = \left\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ errors.  Now
suppose that the received word $\mathbf r$ has $e$ errors
and $\varepsilon$ erasures in it. Note that the receiver
knows the locations of $\varepsilon$ erasures but it does not know the location of the errors; *indeed, the receiver does not even know 
the value of $e$ !*  Thus, Steps I and II create purported
received words $\mathbf r_0$ and $\mathbf r_1$ at distances $e+\varepsilon_0$ and $e+\varepsilon_1$ from the transmitted
codeword where $\varepsilon_0 + \varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon$.
Now, *if $2e+\varepsilon < d$, then at least one (possibly both)
of $\mathbf r_0$ and $\mathbf r_1$ is at distance at most
$t$ from the transmitted codeword.*  Consequently, at least one
(and possibly both) of $\mathbf c_0$ and $\mathbf c_1$ is the
transmitted codeword.  While we are guaranteed that at least
one of Steps I and II returns the transmitted codeword, the
*other* Step might result in a decoder failure (and we know already
how to handle that case in Step III), but, in general, it is
possible for the other Step to return a *different* codeword.

Example: Suppose that a codeword of weight $4$ in the binary
$[8,4]$ extended Hamming code is transmitted and that three
of the four $1$'s get erased. Then, $\mathbf r_0$ has weight $1$
and gets decoded into the all-$0$ codeword with one error being
corrected in the decoding process, while $\mathbf r_1$
is the transmitted codeword itself and so gets decoded into 
the transmitted codeword with no errors being corrected in the
decoding process.

So, what should be done when Steps I and II return different
codewords $\mathbf c_0$ and $\mathbf c_1$? *The answer is that
Step III should return the result of whichever Step corrected
fewer errors.*  Is it possible for Steps I and II to correct the same number of errors?
Yes, but in this case, they are guaranteed to return the same codeword,
not different codewords *as long as the constraint $2e+\varepsilon < d$
is satisfied.* Of course, the decoder does not know whether the constraint is satisfied or not, and, as Jyrki's example in the comments
shows, it is possible for Steps I and II to return different codewords
with the same number of errors being corrected in each case.

In the absence of the side information referred to in
Jyrki's comment, we modify Step III slightly to

- **Step III:** If exactly one Step I or Step II results
  in a valid codeword,
  return that codeword as the most likely transmitted codeword. If both Steps I and II return the same valid codeword, return that codeword
  as the most likely transmitted codeword. If Steps I and II result
  in different codewords, then return the result of whichever Step corrected fewer errors, but if both Steps corrected the same number of
  errors, then declare a decoding failure.

Comment: This works, but a modicum of care is needed in case errors and erasures may have happened. With the [8,4] extended Hamming code we could have received $1??0\ 0000$. When feeding the decoder $1000\ 0000$, it will gladly decode it as $0000\ 0000$. When feeding it $1110\ 0000$, it will happily output $1111\ 0000$. A closer examination reveals that both attempts lead to a case of a single error and two erasures which is beyond the bound of the error/erasure correction capacity.

Comment: Anyway, the extra I want to emphasize is that if Steps 1 and 2 return **different** codewords, you should not necessarily accept either (unless extra soft information is available).

Comment: And these comments are my *thank you* to Dilip. He taught me about this pitfall years ago in sci.math (in connection with the [7,4] Hamming code), so I want to check if I pass this time! +1, of course :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen All decoding algorithms discuss what happens when the number of errors and erasures meet the specified constraints and very few discuss what happens when the constraints are not met.